# Pre-fill powershell parameters with modify option

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-ise, powershell-4.0

I have a powershell script such as this :

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
   [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
   [string]$age="8"
   )

process
{
    Write-Host "Your age is $age"
}
```

How can I modify this script so that the shell asks me for age and puts 8 besides it but allows the user to change the value before pressing enter ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're asking for, but i'd do it like this.

```
 [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
       [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
       [string]$age="8"
       )

    process
    {
    $yourage = "8" + $age 
        Write-Host "Your age is $yourage"
    }
```

If age = 29
Returns: Your age is 829

Comment: I see what you mean. But I want powershell to show age prompt as `age:5` and then allow me to replace that or use it on the prompt itself. Can't get that to work ...

Comment: Sounds like you need `Read-InputBoxDialog`
`Read-InputBoxDialog -Message "Enter Your Age" -WindowTitle "Example" -DefaultText "5"`

Comment: Hmm...I don't think I need windows dialog box, but is that the only solution or their is an another way? Should I accomplish the objective in some other way ?

Comment: Thats the best way i can think of to accomplish what you need, unless you can do the same with `Read-Host` and `Write-Host`